# $\ell$-adic cohomology of varieties through a surjective proper map $X\to Y$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, etale-cohomology

This is a naïve question regarding etale cohomology.

I consider $\ell$-adic cohomology of algebraic varieties defined over an algebraic closure $\mathbb F_p$ with $p\not = \ell$. Assume given two projective varieties $X,Y$ together with a surjective proper map
$$\pi:X\to Y.$$
Is there a systematic way to relate the cohomology groups $\mathrm H_c^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb Q_{\ell})$ and $\mathrm H_c^{\bullet}(Y,\mathbb Q_{\ell})$ together with the cohomology of the various fibers $X_y := \pi^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in Y$ ?

If moreover $X$ and $Y$, as well as the morphism $\pi$, are defined over $\mathbb F_q$ where $q$ is a power of $p$, is there a way to keep track of the Frobenius eigenvalues between these different cohomology groups ?

Comment: I mean in general there is the Leray spectral sequence https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03QC together with the fact that the stalks of $(R^i \pi_\ast \mathbb{Q}_\ell)_y$, as $\pi$ is proper, can be identified with $H^i(\pi^{-1}(y),\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ (combine https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03Q9 and https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A0B).

Comment: For your second question, because you are dealing with spectral sequences, you can really only keep track of alternating sums. In this case, what you want follows pretty easily from the above (e.g. see Theorem 2.6 of this: https://wiki.epfl.ch/quetorus/documents/l-adic%20-%20lausanne.pdf )

Comment: Thank you @AlexYoucis , this seems to be precisely what I was looking for!